# Prometheus Backup and Restore - How to backup and restore metrics data, alerts, servicemonitors/job from old prometheus to new prometheus

Tags: backup, prometheus, monitoring, persistent-volumes, prometheus-operator

I want to export metrics data, alerts, servicemonitors from one prometheus to another prometheus.

- How snapshot backup and restore works as in what all things are backed up (only
  metrics data (or) servicemonitors/jobs, alerts, metrics is everything
  backed up)?
- How to restore the snapshot in new prometheus?
- How to verify if the metrics are imported to new prometheus?
- Also is there a way to take backup of alert rules,
  servicemonitors/jobs and restore it to new prometheus?

Note: Prometheus is deployed using Kube-prometheus-stack/prometheus-operator

Found few posts which suggests to use "snapshot" or "pointing to old PV" methods to backup the prometheus data.

1. I deleted the previous folder and added my new snapshot folder as
   suggested in these links -
   https://suraj.io/post/how-to-backup-and-restore-prometheus/
   https://devopstales.github.io/kubernetes/backup-and-retore-prometheus/
   But couldn't able to see the restored data in new prometheus.
2. Tried Pointing my Persistent volume to old PV as mentioned here
   -https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/
   In this method also i couldn't able to see metrics,
   servicemonitors/jobs, alerts getting backed up!